# using CKAN with Elasticsearch to index data , possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, ckan, opendata

I'm trying to use an open data portal which is CKAN . However its search platform uses solr , but i want to use elasticsearch to index my data . Is this a way to use elasticsearch with CKAN ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

ES is probably more popular now, but I can't think of any really good reason to switch from SOLR. They are both just wrappers around Lucene. Please do say what your reasoning is.

It's certainly doable, since the coupling with SOLR is reasonably loose. There was some work towards this here: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3118 which no doubt you'd be welcome to help resource.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Actually , ES provides many features that helps in exploring data and loading it from many sources ... especially with the ELK stack . https://db-engines.com/en/blog_post/55

Comment: CKAN uses SOLR to store the metadata (the catalog of datasets), rather than the data. CKAN's DataStore stores data in postgres. There's an argument that ES is more suited to large analytic flows, compared to Postgres. For what you want to do, you would have a metadata record in CKAN for each dataset (as normal), and the resource.url links to your data published in ES (rather than enabling DataStore).